# Role authentications without utilizing database

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Is it possible to use role base authentication without the use of a DB?

I have a one-off web app which basically will have only 1 admin user.

The rest of the users will have access only to pages in a particular folder, while the one admin user will have access to the pages in all the folders.

Everything I searched so far has the roles tying back to a db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what technologies you are using, you could override authentication methods and hard code a username and password to something in your web.config file.  You can also specify users via web.config files under the authorization section.

```
<authorization>
   <allow users="localAdmin\myAdminUser" />
</authorization>
```

and in your authentication code:

```
if (authenticated_username == webConfigUsername && autheticated_password == webConfigPassword) {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(authenticated_username, true);
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

Or you could add the admin user during the authentication process to a group and do security via group membership:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admins"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And given your question / comment, I'd look at implementing a customer role provider.  The basics of it would be to implement the methods you need to get the basics of your application working.  Instead of going to a DB, you'd most likely be working with the Session object.  Check out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) on how to create a custom role provider.  You'd then be able to keep your web.config files clean, and then just put the roles the users are in via the overrides based off usernames.

Comment: I'm trying to do the group membership via web.config.  However I'm not sure how to set the role in the code behind.  I tried Roles.AddUserToRole, but thats when it generates SqlException error.

Comment: Would this be the easiest route?  Basically I have a folder of pages that only 1 user will ever be able to access.

Comment: The easiest route would be to use Windows Authentication, deny unauthenticated users using a web.config, and then allow on the admin folder the particular user that is admin.  This way, you keep .config authentication, you forget about a database and you keep your app secure.